# Telegram permitted callback_data size less than file_id size

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I need to resend file id in callback data like that:

```
cd1 = 'publish {}'.format(new_file_id)
cd2 = 'delayed 1 {} *'.format(new_file_id)
...
markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(1)
btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Publish',
                                      callback_data=cd1)
btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Delayed publication',
                                      callback_data=cd2)
markup.add(btn1, btn2)

bot.edit_message_reply_markup(message.chat.id, msg.message_id, reply_markup=markup)
```

But size of file_id, which I get as

```
new_file_id = msg.video_note.file_id
```

*(Standard method of https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI)*
more than permitted callback_data size (1-64 bytes).

Actual size for `callback_data`'s strings is 128 bytes for cd1 and 132 bytes for cd2.

`file_id` looks like `DQACAgIAAxkDAAIHZ14-nxWa7ckt2ZG7UQMrq_PuxIxRAAK4BQACzfj4SdBn7Y70cYWSGAQ` and size is 120 bytes.

Any ideas? Really hope on your help.

Comment: First idea is just store in db pairs like ```id-telegram_file_id```, so id will have less size (up to 32bytes). But that isn't looks like good (beauty) solution.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and looks like there is no way to send a `file_id` in the callback data.

If you are taking the `file_id` from a message sent to your bot, a workaround can be using the `message_id` which is a progressive index that identifies the message in the chat.

Unfortunately Telegram API doesn't have a method which let you recover a past message having its id, but when you receive the message you may store a mapping `message_id -> file_id` (in memory or in a db) and pass the key in as callback_data.

Sure it's not the best thing in the world but I think it's the best thing we can have until they increase the size of callback_data.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it with storing *file_id* in a table containing: *id* (int) and *file_id*(text) and wrote it's *id* in **callback_data**. When I receive **callback_data** with id, I can get the *file_id*